# Program stops responding when I try to increment and print a number in a loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, freeze

I have the following code in **C#**:

```
void Update () {
    for (int m=0;m<122132343243243;m++)
    {
        print(m);
    }
}
```

When I try run this Unity stops responding. How can I get this function to finish executing?

Comment: Even if you get this working without a runtime error, it's trying to print over 100 trillion numbers in a row, so it'd stop responding...are you sure doing this all in a single frame is what you really want?

Comment: ...stop responding I cannot do anything. ....How to wait until this end?

Comment: The program will be locked up until it finishes counting to 122 trillion. Which will take a very, very long time. Maybe consider putting this in a coroutine and counting up once every iteration, so you can at least see its progress and stop after you've had enough?

Comment: You defined m as an integer. The number 122132343243243 is way beyond what any 32-bit integer can store. At some point your program will overflow. Use a long instead.

Comment: @Daniel even in that way it is not responding

Comment: @StepHan Please refer to [Unity's documentation on coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to learn how to spread out lengthy tasks over multiple frames, so they're less likely to stop responding.

Comment: @Serlite I don't need counting up every iteration...So how it can be  in `coroutine`

Comment: @StepHan The problem is that you're asking a massive task of the computer - it can't count up to 122 trillion in a single ideal frame (1/60 of a second), so it locks up until it can finish the task. But that is a very, very large number, meaning your program probably won't be responding for at least 20 days (see http://startdebugging.net/counting-up-to-one-trillion/). And even worse is that you're printing the number, which is a lot slower than writing to a variable. So you need to spread out the work over multiple frames with a coroutine, or it will stop responding effectively forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're asking the computer to do a massive amount of work all at once, so it stops responding. Counting up to 122 trillion is a lengthy task, which by itself would take at least 20 days (see *[Counting up to one trillion](http://startdebugging.net/counting-up-to-one-trillion/)* for estimation) and is only compounded by the fact that you're printing every number.

What you need to do is allow the computer to spread this work out over multiple frames, through the use of [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). (You could use another thread instead to prevent locking, but coroutines are the simpler Unity approach to this problem.)

Your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine("CountAndPrint");
}

IEnumerator CountAndPrint() {
    for (long m=0; m<122132343243243; m++) {
        print(m);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

*Note: I also switched `long` in for `int`, as Daniel noted that the value of `m` will otherwise overflow should you let it run for long enough.*

The main difference in this code is that it basically allows the program to "pause" execution of the method after each time it counts up, saving the rest of the work for future frames. This will allow you to continue interacting with the program while the counter increases.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.